# Need to use getBoundingClientRect() in Vue 3 Composition API within a v-for loop

Tags: javascript, vuejs3

I need to convert the below piece of code in Vue 3 Composition API so I can get the position of the element. Currently I tried converting this but its not at all working out. Please if someone can shed some light on this.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="index in divs" :key="index">
      <div :ref="'ref_' + index" @mouseover="divDragOver($event, index)">
        This is div {{ index }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
export default {
  name: 'App',
  data: () => ({
    divs: [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10],
  }),
  methods: {
    divDragOver(e, i) {
      let [div] = this.$refs['ref_' + i];
      let top = div.getBoundingClientRect().top;
      console.log(top);
    },
  },
};
</script>
```

This is what I am trying to do, but I am unable to figure this out.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="index in divs" :key="index">
      <div :ref="'ref_' + index" @mouseover="divDragOver($event, index)">
        This is div {{ index }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

  const divs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

  function divDragOver(e, i) {
    let itemRefs = ['ref_' + i]
    let top = itemRefs.getBoundingClientRect().top
    console.log(top)
  }
</script>
```

This is exactly where I am trying to implement the concept please have a look.

```
<template>
    <li v-for="item in navigation" :key="item.name" class="px-1">
        <Menu
            as="div"
            v-slot="{ open }"
            class="relative"
            :ref="(el) => (refs[item.name] = el)"
        >
            <MenuButton
                :class="[
                    item.current ? 'bg-gray-100' : 'hover:bg-gray-100',
                    'group flex h-10 w-full items-center justify-center rounded-md p-2.5 text-standard font-semibold leading-6 text-gray-700',
                ]"
                @click="getParentPosition($event, item.name)"
            >
                <span
                    class="-mx-2.5 flex w-10 flex-none items-center justify-center"
                >
                    <component
                        :is="item.icon"
                        class="h-5 w-5 shrink-0 text-gray-400"
                        aria-hidden="true"
                    />
                </span>
            </MenuButton>
            <transition
                enter-active-class="transition ease-out duration-100"
                enter-from-class="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
                enter-to-class="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                leave-active-class="transition ease-in duration-75"
                leave-from-class="transform opacity-100 scale-100"
                leave-to-class="transform opacity-0 scale-95"
            >
                <MenuItems
                    class="fixed left-14 z-10 mt-1.5 w-32 origin-top-right rounded-md bg-white py-2 shadow-md ring-1 ring-gray-900/5 focus:outline-none"
                >
                    <MenuItem
                        v-for="subItem in item.children"
                        :key="subItem.name"
                        v-slot="{ active }"
                    >
                        <a
                            :href="item.href"
                            :class="[
                                active ? 'bg-gray-50' : '',
                                'block px-3 py-1 text-standard leading-6 text-gray-500',
                            ]"
                        >
                            {{ subItem.name }}
                        </a>
                    </MenuItem>
                </MenuItems>
            </transition>
        </Menu>
    </li>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const refs = ref([])

function getParentPosition(e, k) {
    let itemRef = refs.value[k]
    console.log(itemRef)
}
</script>
```

Would really like to thank the community for the help and support.

Comment: `Currently I tried converting this` perhaps you could show what you tried, then someone can show you what you did wrong - as a guess, you'll probably want [function refs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#function-refs)

Comment: @JaromandaX Thanks for the advise, have done that already.

Comment: Apparently you didn't read that documentation ... `let itemRefs = ['ref_' + i]`?? that's not it

Comment: @JaromandaX I am not understanding ahead what to do, that's the reason I am seeking help, please guide me here.

Comment: My suggestion was to use "function refs" - seems you didn't read the documentation I linked to - added an answer anyway

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As i said in the comment, you need to use [function refs](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html#function-refs)

So, in the code below, we first set up a variable, lets say `const refs = ref([])`

Then, the "function ref" is written like `:ref="(el) => refs[index] = el"` as per the documentation

Now to access the ref ... `let itemRef = refs.value[i];`

Full code:

```
<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

  const divs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
  const refs = ref([]);
  function divDragOver(e, i) {
    let itemRef = refs.value[i];
    let top = itemRef.getBoundingClientRect().top
    console.log(top)
  }
</script>

<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="index in divs" :key="index">
      <div :ref="(el) => refs[index] = el" @mouseover="divDragOver($event, index)">
        This is div {{ index }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>
```

---

edit:

Your original question was using `index` as a key, i.e. a number from 0...n

Seems you actually use a string as the key, so, you need to set refs to be an `Object`, not an `Array`

instead of

```
  const refs = ref([]);
```

use

```
  const refs = ref({});
```

No need for any changes in your latest `<template>`

Comment: Really appreciate your response, but I am getting this error when I am trying to do it `Uncaught TypeError: itemRef.getBoundingClientRect is not a function`

Comment: @ToxifiedM - You're doing something wrong in that case - the code I posted works, just like the code the other answer posted works - the common denominator for failure is your unseen attempt at using the answers

Comment: I am getting this as object when I am console logging `itemRef`

https://ibb.co/2sw7Kg6

Comment: @ToxifiedM - without seeing your attempt at the code, I don't see the relevance of your image

Comment: Hey, apologizes for that, I have updated the exact piece of code where I am trying to implement the solution, please spare some time if you can to have a look.

Comment: Oh, see, in your ORIGINAL code you used index ... a number ... now you're using a name, presumably NOT a number - so, instead of `const refs = ref([])` use `const refs = ref({})`

Comment: I did that still its an object when I am console logging it, I am just not understating what the issue is.

Comment: Someone at discord suggested me to add `$el` at the end of the `itemRef` it seems to work now, is it the right way to do it? This is how the code looks like now `let top = itemRef.$el.getBoundingClientRect().top`

Comment: depends on the ref you get I guess. I think that has to do with the fact that the ref is on a component - not sure

Comment: Yes might be the case but thanks a lot for your continuous help!

Answer (score 2):

After a bit of tinkering around, I refactored your code to tame it composition API way. The problem here is that you are trying to call the getBoundingClientRect() method on a string array, which is not possible since it's not an actual DOM element.

Using `:ref="el => (divRefs[index] = el)"` does the magic you want there. Then the rest of the logic is similar to what you've done already.

```
<template>
  <div>
    <div v-for="index in divs" :key="index">
      <div :ref="el => (divRefs[index] = el)" @mouseover="divDragOver($event, index)">
        This is div {{ index }}
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script setup>
import { ref } from 'vue'

const divs = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
const divRefs = {}

function divDragOver(e, i) {
  let itemRef = divRefs[i]
  if (itemRef) {
    let top = itemRef.getBoundingClientRect().top
    console.log(top)
  }
}
</script>
```

Sandbox for testing: https://codesandbox.io/s/nostalgic-knuth-vdwmp8?file=/src/App.vue:0-499

Comment: Really appreciate your response, I am getting the following error `Uncaught TypeError: itemRef.getBoundingClientRect is not a function`

Comment: Did you try the sandbox link I gave? The App is working fine there without errors. You can play around with the code there even..

Comment: Proof: https://imgur.com/a/gRrh10y

Comment: I am getting this as object when I am console logging `itemRef`, please check

https://ibb.co/2sw7Kg6

Comment: TL;DR: Your value is inside the "Target" object :)

@ToxifiedM I'm not sure this is related to the original problem but yes, this is the new way to get the value of a ref or computed variable (composition api). Ideally, if your variable is like this, const variableName = ref('hello)', then you can get the value in the script like this console.log(variableName.value).  See -- https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/template-refs.html and https://vuejs.org/api/reactivity-core.html#ref

Comment: Hey, I have updated the exact piece of code where I am trying to implement the solution, please spare some time if you can to have a look.